# Calculating mean follow up from ONLY sample size and range

Tags: mean, sample-size, stata, approximate-bayesian-computation

I have several observational studies (mostly historical, prior to 1950s) that are looking at relapse rate across several years of follow up period for depression. I only have MINIMUM and MAXIMUM follow up period and sample size (ie one study reports a follow up period of 10-15 years for a sample size of 208 people). However no mean follow up period is provided.
I know from knowledge of the subject/relapse rate trends in modern studies on the same subject that it is a left skewed distribution- ie there will be more relapses in the early period of the study for each individual and then they will become less frequent with time.

So on this basis, ie knowing **sample size**, **range**, and **type of distribution**, is it possible to calculate mean follow up period? Also on STATA, since that is the software i am required to use for this project.
Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of distribution? You state that it is left skewed, but that is only very little information about the type of distribution.

Answer (score 5):

You would need to have some idea how relapse times are distributed within the interval.

For example, if they are exponentially distributed, then
the mean of a moderate number of relapse times is roughly 17% of the way from the minimum to the maximum.

Here is a simulation for 200 subjects; results for 100 and were about 19% and results for 500
were about the 15%.

```
set.seed(2021)
m = 10^5;  v = a = w = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
 x = rexp(200)
 v[i] = min(x); a[i] = mean(x); w[i] = max(x)
 }
mean(v); mean(a); mean(w)
[1] 0.00499292
[1] 0.9999175
[1] 5.875548
(mean(a)-mean(v))/(mean(w)-mean(v))
[1] 0.1694771
```

*Note:* For a uniform relapse distribution, results were about 50%.

Comment: If they are exponentially distributed then the mean might be 17% between minimum and maximum, but the example gives a minimum of 10 years and maximum of 15 years. Is this minimum at 2/3 of the maximum a likely outcome when the distribution is exponential?

Comment: Depends. of course, on what's counted in the 10-15 yr, span.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on BruceET's answer, you must have some idea as to how the relapses are distributed. The exponential is a one-parameter distribution: once you know its mean, you know its variance and how all the quantiles are distributed. Anything more complex, such as a gamma or a Weibull—which are also right-tailed, left-moded distributions—will harder to solve, but if you restrict yourself to a two-parameter distribution, you may be able get an estimate.

Clearly, you have to set an assumed percentile as your seen maximum. You *cannot* have the entire distribution as most of these are defined for the entire real non-negative number line. While the minimum may well be the 0th percentile, that will not help us. Since 0 is the minimum for **every** such distribution. But if we can say it is the 1st or second, we now have two "pieces" of information: the min and the max serving as our estimates of the 2% and 98%, so we can reverse engineer the quantile functions for a given distribution to get two parameters, and thus the mean.

For example. Let's use the Pareto parameterized with shape $\alpha$ and scale. $\theta$. The CDF of the Pareto is:

$$
F(x) = p = 1 - \left(\frac{\theta}{x+\theta}\right)^\alpha
$$

Which means:

$$
x = \frac{\theta}{\left(1-p\right)^\frac{1}{\alpha}} - \theta
$$

If you have fixed your minimum as $p_1 = 0.02$ and your maximum as $p_2 = 0.98$ you can solve for $\alpha$ and $\theta$ and then use those parameters to estimate the mean.

Some distributions don't have closed forms without the use of special functions (gamma, beta, etc.) and so a brute force technique can be used. Forgive my use of R; I don't know stata. The following function returns the sum of the squared error between the min and the quantile representing $p_1$ and the max and the quantile representing $p_2$.

```r
RangeErrGam <- function(par, min, max, p1, p2) {
  shp <- par[[1]]
  scl <- par[[2]]
  (min - qgamma(p1, shp, scale = scl)) ^ 2 +
    (max - qgamma(p2, shp, scale = scl)) ^ 2
}
```

Minimizing this error will result in parameters which can be used for estimating the mean. Let's say your minimum was 5 weeks and your maximum was 35 weeks.

```r
fit <- optim(c(3, 10), RangeErrGam, min = 5, max = 35, p1 = 0.02, p2 = 0.98,
             method = 'Nelder-Mead', control = list(maxit = 1e4))
```

This results in:

```r
> fit
$par
[1] 4.947039 3.332601

$value
[1] 6.43681e-06

$counts
function gradient 
     147       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

So the mean relapse time would be shape * scale or about 16.5 weeks.

Plotting this distribution shows the characteristics you wanted (left-mode, right-tail):

```r
curve(dgamma(x, shape = fit$par[1], scale = fit$par[2]), from = 0, to = 50)
abline(v = fit$par[1] * fit$par[2])
```

[image]

This method can be extended to any two-parameter distribution.

Comment: (+1) The exponential no-memory property helps to simplify the distribution within the specified interval.

Comment: Dear @BruceET and Avraham thank you ever so much for helping me out with this. I am a medical doctor so clearly very far removed from the ever burgeoning world of data modeling- so please bear with me if my query sounds really stupid! I had a follow up question re parametric value. was the parametric value c(3,10) determined through brute force in your example? If so why did you chose that? Is it because we need to keep the $value as close to 0 as possible?

Comment: I will let @Avraham explain what distribution and parameters he has chosen and why. // I think he may have given his Answer fearing that mine is too simple to work. My idea may be worth trying briefly to see whether it seems to work, according to your intuition. But he may be right. // An even simpler idea to try might be to pick the midpoint between the max and the min. I do not see how it is possible to retrieve _exact_ means from the records available. // I will follow this discussion and join again if I think I have a worthwhile new idea.

Comment: Thank you so much :). Just to give you a bit more of an idea if it helps... the project itself is a meta-analysis of historical relapse rates in bipolar disorder (before modern pharmacological treatments came into play). So it is quite a bit of maneuvering the data to fit our modern reporting systems. The relapse rates reported in those old papers are over a follow up period (they give us min and max follow up period but no means). Without a mean follow up period we cannot make comparisons with modern studies.

Comment: So in essence it is trying to get a mean from a range. There is only one paper where they have given a range 1-20 years with mean 3.2 years (hence why I think the mean for others should also sit closer to the minimum rather than the maximum). I used @Avraham's code to see if I get a computed mean that is close to that. and I did get 2.89. So I think it could work for others too... the model is sound. I just want to understand how he got to the parameter. Sorry for the lengthy explanation!!

Comment: @MutahiraQ, the c(3, 10) in the call to `optim` is just a set of initial parameters. `optim` is a local minimizer. However, for a two-parameter distribution there should not be that many close to each other, so any reasonable set of starting parameters should converge to the nearest local minimum. The important parameters are the fitted ones! My answer  is very similar to @BruceET's but somewhat more flexible in that IF you are willing to peg the min and max at set percentiles, THEN you can brute force a minimum distance fit to a two-parameter distribution of your choice.

Comment: @MutahiraQ, also, you can try using different two parameter distributions, such as the Weibull, the Pareto and their inverse versions. R does not have a built-in `d/p/q/rpareto` but you can easily write your own or use the `actuar` package for that one. Perhaps one of those will provide an even closer fit.

Comment: @Avraham thank you so much for taking out the time to help me out :). Will try my best to fit this to my specs now!